# Weka Percentage split gives different result than train/test split

Tags: weka

When I use the Percentage split option in Weka I get good results:

Correctly Classified Instances         286              |86.1446 %

What I expect it to do, and what I read in the docs, is to split the data into training and testing based on the percentage I define. The problem is now, if I split it with a filter->RemovePercentage and train it with the exact same amount of training and testing data I get these result for the testing data:

Correctly Classified Instances         183   |            55.1205 %

The test set is for both exactly 332 instances. Why are these results not about the same?
I expect it to be the same as I do the same thing.

Comment: Does this still occur when turning off randomization (*more options...*)? Otherwise you are comparing the result of two different sets of train/test subsets.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the randomization has caused that gap. Is there anything you can do about it to improve the performance non randomized?

Comment: No. It just shows that the order in your data affects performance. Use cross-validation for better estimates. Even better, run 10 times 10-fold CV in the Experimenter (default settimg). That'll give you mean/stdev between runs as well, hinting at stability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by [fracpete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4698227/fracpete) the percentage split randomizes the sample by default, this has caused this large gap. You can turn it off under "more options".